# Apple In App Purchase and external subscriptions

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

A quick question regarding Apples in app purchase rules and exactly what qualifies as an 'external mechanism' for purchasing outside of an app.

We have been building apps with IAP for a while so I know the rules, however we are thinking about doing the following with an update of a popular App and I would be curious to get your feedback, do you think this complies with Apples rules? I have to say the guidelines are a little vague at times,

- Our app is free, however to unlock functionality after a trial period you have to subscribe.
- We will offer two versions of the product, *single user* and *multi user*.
- Single User can be purchased in app using IAP.
- Multi User can be activated in app (in effect giving a secondary trial period) however when you activate it we email you to complete purchase outside of the app.
- If you don't complete the external purchase after a period of time the app will downgrade back to the free version. The user will get lots of notice of this.
- There is no reference to purchasing Multi User in the app and at no point in the app do we link to an external place for you to purchase it. It is all done via email.

Looking at the rules:

> 7.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected, except in cases where the application hosts plug-ins or extensions
>
> 7.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

Do you think our plans obey the rules? I know its ok to offer subscriptions outside of the app store, even at a different price, but a different type of subscription thats not even listed in the app?

Very interested in your view.

Comment: Did you ever get any good info on this?

Answer (score 2):

I found an article that describes subscriptions in App Store: 
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

> Subscriptions Purchased Outside of an App Subscribers who were
>   acquired outside of your app can read or play content through the app.
>   However, you may not provide external links in your app that allow
>   users to purchase subscriptions outside of the app.